# MYSQL Query optimization for slow query

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

I have a query below which is quite slow and I know could be optmized. It takes 0.0479 seconds, but this is because it is sorted on a calculated field.  In the select statement, I select the advert_id column which is the primary key of the table.  If I ammend the query below, not to select the primary key of advert_id, but leave everything else the same it only takes 0.0098 seconds to run.

```
SELECT adverts.advert_id, round( sqrt( ( ( (adverts.latitude - '51.558430') * (adverts.latitude - '51.558430') ) * 69.1 * 69.1 ) + ( (adverts.longitude - '-0.0069345') * (adverts.longitude - '-0.0069345') * 53 * 53 ) ), 1 ) as distance
FROM adverts
WHERE (adverts.status = 1) AND (adverts.approved = 1) 
AND (adverts.latitude BETWEEN 51.2692837281 AND 51.8475762719) 
AND (adverts.longitude BETWEEN -0.472015213613 AND 0.458146213613) 
having (distance <= '20') 
ORDER BY distance ASC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

On the first query, the explain says is using the 'sall' index below but the extra colum is set to 'Using where; Using filesort'.

When I ammend the query to not select the advert_id, the explain says its using the 'sall' index but the extra column is set to 'Using where; Using index; Using filesort'.

The 'sall' index includes the following columns :

status
approved
latitude
longitude

I tried creating another index but adding the advert_id before the status, hoping the first query would use this and be quicker, but when I forced it to use the index, it was even slower.

Comment: The `HAVING` clause applies only to results of aggregate functions on queries including a `GROUP BY` clause (maybe MySQL is more lenient in this regard than Oracle?) -- The distance test should be part of the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add advert_id to the end of the index, not the beginning.

This will allow the query to be processed using only the index (which is what "Using index" means) but will not disrupt the efficient search the index is already providing.

Also, as Jim Garrison pointed out, you probably should add "GROUP BY adverts.advert_id" to your query before the HAVING clause.